# iOS framework with multiple, distinct set of headers

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, ios-frameworks

I got a very strange request from one of my customers (at least according to my current knowledge). I have to build an iOS framework, which main purpose is to wrap a C/C++ library with Obj-C code, to hide some of its general API and expose only what my customer want me to expose via Obj-C. Now, here comes the tricky part. This framework is going to be a dependency for an application (objects/methods/functions/whatever should be accessible from , i.e. view controllers) and for another framework. Is it possible to build this framework in a way that expose only part of an API to an application and part of API to another framework which is going to use it internally? 
According to my knowledge it is impossible and framework can expose only one API, which is common to every possible consumer/user. However my knowledge might not be complete in this topic.

Additional question: can I expose both Obj-C and C API from a single framework. I assume I can, but just want to make sure.

Please don't ask about rationale behind this idea. This is a requirement I got and have to investigate so I can't provide any sensible justification at the moment.

Thanks!